# The average value of $\zeta(1/2+it)$ at Gram points is 2

Tags: reference-request, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

It is stated in $\textit{Riemann’s Zeta Function}$ (H.M. Edwards) in the footnote of p126 that the average value of $\zeta(1/2+it)$ at Gram points is 2 - he cites Section 11.1 of the paper

ON VAN DER CORPUT'S METHOD AND THE ZETA-FUNCTION OF RIEMANN (IV), E. C. TITCHMARSH,
The Quarterly Journal of Mathematics, Volume os-5, Issue 1, 1934, Pages 98–105, https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/os-5.1.98

I have looked at this paper and there is no Section 11.1 and I do not see this result mentioned anywhere. Where can I find this result of Titchmarsh?

Comment: It is proved in the paper on page 101 line 3, where Titchmarsh proves that $\sum_{M+1}^N(-1)^{\nu}f(t_{\nu})/N \to 1, N \to \infty$ where $M$ is large fixed since that is $1/2$ of the average of $\zeta$ at the gram points $1/2+it_{\nu}$. Note that Titchmarsh forgets a $2$ in the expression for $f$ which comes from $a+\bar a=2\Re a=2\cos (\theta_a), a=re^{i\theta}$ - see Edwards p 139 for the correct expression (Edwards calls it by the modern terminology $Z$ or the Hardy function)

Comment: a modern proof of the result (with the correct $2$!) is in Ivic's book on the Hardy function on page 113, Thm 6.5;  https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/theory-of-hardys-zfunction/573BAE2181B686A8CF463A75C48DE1AD